# Valor de input irreal y uso de booleanos en atributo value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Buenas noches: Tengo 2 problemas al usar el atributo value de los inputs tipo text en HTML:
El primero es que se ve un valor equis en el input que no es el mismo que veo al utilizar la consola, sobretodo me pasa cuando utilizo booleanos.

En mi caso tengo 4 inputs que tienen el value en "false" cuando se carga el formulario, dependiendo de ciertos procesos les cambio el valor (sólo a true) por medio de JQuery con la instrucción $('#idinput').val('true'); y a pesar de que se ve en el input la frase "true", cuando abro la consola se ve el value del input en "false".

El segundo es que a pesar de cambiar ese valor en la consola no lo cambia en el input.
He googleado el problema pero no he conseguido ninguna respuesta.

Agradecería la ayuda

HTML

````
      <div class="col">  
            <label for="datos_filiatorios">Datos Filiatorios</label>  
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm inputs_centrados" name="datos_filiatorios" id="datos_filiatorios" value="false" readonly>  
      </div>  
</div>```

`jquery
if (cedula_user > 0 && apellido_user > 0 && nombre_user > 0 && clave_user > 0 && correo_user > 0 && division_user > 0 && tipo_user > 0 && grupo_user > 0 && estatus_user > 0) {
        $('#datos_filiatorios').val('true');
    } else {
        $('#datos_filiatorios').val('false');
    }`
````

Comment: Donde colocas los console.log , creo que no es una manera adecuada de usar ese if

Answer (score 0):

Esto simula tu ejemplo si es que manejas los valores como strings, podria ser problema de alguna otra parte de tu codigo

```js
function ponerFalse() {
  $('#datos_filiatorios').val('false');
}

function ponerTrue() {
  $('#datos_filiatorios').val('true');
}

function valorActual() {
  console.log($('#datos_filiatorios').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
  <label for="datos_filiatorios">Datos Filiatorios</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm inputs_centrados" name="datos_filiatorios" id="datos_filiatorios" value="false" readonly>
</div>

<button onclick="ponerTrue();">Poner 'true'</button>
<button onclick="ponerFalse();">Poner 'false'</button>
<button onclick="valorActual();">Ver valor</button>
```